# Access function from within scripts and from commandline

Tags: python

### I want to do the following:

I have a class which should provide several functions, which need different inputs. And I would like to use these functions from within other scripts, or solely from commandline.

e.g. I have the class "test". It has a function "quicktest" (which basically justs prints something). (From commandline) I want to be able to

```
$ python test.py quicktest "foo" "bar"
```

Whereas quicktest is the name of the function, and "foo" and "bar" are the variables.

Also (from within another script) I want to

```
from test import test

# this
t = test()
t.quicktest(["foo1", "bar1"])

# or this
test().quicktest(["foo2", "bar2"])
```

I just can't bring that to work. I managed to write a class for the first request and one for the second, but not for both of them. The problem is that I sometimes have to call the functions via (self), sometimes not, and also I have to provide the given parameters at any time, which is also kinda complicated.

So, does anybody have an idea for that?

---

### This is what I already have:

Works only from commandline:

```
class test:
    def quicktest(params):
        pprint(params)

    if (__name__ == '__main__'):
        if (sys.argv[1] == "quicktest"):
            quicktest(sys.argv)
        else:
            print "Wrong call."
```

Works only from within other scripts:

```
class test:
    _params = sys.argv 

    def quicktest(self, params):
        pprint(params)
        pprint(self._params)

    if (__name__ == '__main__'):
        if (sys.argv[1] == "quicktest"):
            quicktest()
        else:
            print "Wrong call"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following (note that the different indentation, the `if __name__` part is **not** part of class `test` anymore):

```
class test:
    def quicktest(params):
         pprint(params)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[1] == "quicktest":
        testObj = test()
        testObj.quicktest(sys.argv)
    else:
        print "Wrong call."
```

from other scripts:

```
from test import test
testObj = test()
testObj.quicktest(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, moving the `if __name__` part outside the class did the trick. Didn't expect an answer within seconds, fortiori not for this qierd question ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `if __name__ == '__main__':` block needs to be at the top level:

```
class Test(object): # Python class names are capitalized and should inherit from object
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # parse args here so you can import and call with options too
        self.args = args

    def quicktest(self):
        return 'ret_value'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thx, moving `__main__` to top-level did it. Thx also for the info about Python class names

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the command line with the help of [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) to parse the value from the command line.

Your class which has the method and associate methods to arguments.